# How to know that we're on "the last round" of a .each_slice

Tags: ruby

I have a random amount of days that I'm iterating through like this:

```
@days.each_slice(7) {|week|}
```

and would like to know when I'm on the last set of days (i.e. the last week). What would be an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is by defining this algorithm to detect the last slice of an array:

```
def last_slice( array, i )
    last_slice = (array.count % i == 0) ? i : array.count % i
    array.last( last_slice )
end
```

and then compare it like:

```
if ( week == last_slice( @days, 7 ) )
```

Comment: This test breaks if `@days.size % 7 != 0`.

Comment: It also breaks if there's an earlier week that has the same values as the last week.  Really any approach that compares the values instead of the position is subject to false positives in signalling it's the last of the enumeration.

Comment: @dbenhur, for `if week == @days[-7..-1]` you are right. The same does not stand for `#last` which will [retrieve even 3 elements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-last) if there are only 3. (edited)

Comment: Jueecy, I'm right regardless with either version as value checks get false positives. Also with either version, the modulus requirement effects any set where the set of days is not an even multiple of seven.  If it's less than 7, last will not fail, but if @days.size = 10, for example, @days.last(7) will not match the final slice [`7..9]` either.

Comment: @dbenhur, I must have been drunk yesterday. You are completely right. Final edit.

Comment: This is nicer, but still suffers from false positives as it tests values, not position. Breaking input: `@days = [0] * 14`

Comment: @dbenhur, I always assume that array elements are different if not stated otherwise. In my example the only requirement is that slices are different, which is not that picky. Anyway it seems to be working for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
@days.each_slice(7).with_index do |week,i|
  if i == (@days.size-1)/7
    # last one
  end
  ...
end
```

Alternatively, if your code in the block is highly divergent for the last week:

```
weeks = @days.each_slice(7).to_a
weeks[0...-1].each {|week| ... }
weeks[-1].tap {|last_week| ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a hint,hope will help you:

```
ar = [1,2,3,1,2,3,"a","b","c"]
e = ar.each_slice(3)
e.size.times do |i|
 begin
  i = e.next
  e.peek
 rescue StopIteration
  p "reached last iteration : #{i}"
 end
end
#=> "reached last iteration : [\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

or You could do as below:

```
e = ar.each_slice(3)
e.with_index{|i,ind| p i if ind == e.size - 1 }
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

or You could do as below too:

```
ar = [1,2,3,1,5,3,"a","b","c"]
e = ar.each_slice(3)
e.size.times{|i| i = e.next;p i if !(e.peek rescue nil) }
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: You're on the right track but overcomplicating things a bit. You could just `e.with_index { |days, i| ... }` and check `i == e.size - 1` to detect the last chunk inside the block. And in 1.9.3 (where there is no `e.size`) you could `dm = a.length.divmod(3); size = dm[0] + (dm[1] == 0 ? 0 : 1)` instead of `e.size`.

Comment: @muistooshort I will make it short, using `inline rescue`, working on the same. I am bit confused  with some output.Once I will be confident and will post here. Still working :(

Comment: Yeah, those should work. I'd probably go with `e.with_index` if I was iterating through the whole thing and needed to know when I was on the last one, I tend to prefer exceptions for exceptional circumstances rather than simple flow control.

Answer (score -1):

```
@days.each_slice(7) { |week| if (week.last == @days.last) then <your code here> end }
```

Comment: You could optimize it further by doing `last_day = @days.last` outside the iteration and `if (week.last == last_day)`

Comment: What makes you think that the last element of the `@days` array will be unique in the `week` slices? What if the last element of each week is always the same?

Comment: As @Jueecy.new points out, your test for last can have false positives since you're doing value comparison.  Might be safer to try object identity `week.last.equal? @days.last` though even this could have false positive if multiple elements of days are reference to same object or to same valued immediate objects (like Symbols or Fixnums).

Answer (score -4):

I don't have knowledge of ruby but did you try this in your loop ?

```
@days.each_slice(7) {|week|
    if week.last # do stuff...
}
```

Here is the Ruby Doc for the **each_slice** method :

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice