# Ruby on Rails - Find Last round when using each_slice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

I am using `each_slice` in my application to show a **ad code** every 4 image.

This is how i am doing it:

```
- @post.images.each_slice(4) do |group|
  - group.each do |image|
    // My images

  %div.ads
   // My ads code
```

How can I find the last round and prevent it to show **ad** since I don't want to show ad on last round.

I have done what it says here, But no luck: [How to know that we're on "the last round" of a .each_slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509581/how-to-know-that-were-on-the-last-round-of-a-each-slice)

I added the `last_slide` method in my `post_controller` and get wrong number of arguments when I *run/before_action* it in my `show`-view and when I don't *run* in my controller, nothing happens.

Comment: you could enclose it in an if statement like so `if image.id!=images.last.id`

Comment: Yeah or `if group.include?(images.last)`

Comment: @AAnkudovich It didnt worked:/

Comment: @jphager2 Thanks , It worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in 2 different ways. the first one is a *easy* one, while the second solution is more complex.

1 solution (Thanks to *jphager2* ):

```
if group.include?(images.last)
```

2 solution:

```
- @post.images.each_slice(2).each_with_index do |group, index|
  - group.each_with_index do |image|
   // your code
  - if index < group.size
   // Ad code
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish your goal of inserting an ad between every 4 images, you can take advantage of Rails' render method with the collection and spacer_template options.

```
# The view
= render partial: 'image_group', collection: @images.each_slice(4).to_a, spacer_template: 'advertisement'

# _image_group.html.haml
= render partial: 'image', collection: image_group

# _image.html.haml
// Your image code

# _advertisement.html.haml
%div.ads
  // Your Ads Code
```